# Upgraded PHP to 7.4 and PDO is not found

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, whm

I work for a school that has a new webservice we are trying to build for the school. I wanted to upgrade the PHP from 5.6 to 7.4 so we can run some extensions. However, the website connects to a PostgreSQL database using the PDO function

```
conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=*** dbname=***","***", "***");
```

Now that we upgraded, we are receiving an error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found in
```

I went to easy apache 4 and made sure php74-php-pdo was installed. What else am I missing?

Every day this is broken we will be missing data. Please help.

Comment: Try this first: `$conn = new PDO('pgsql:host=***;dbname=***;user=***;password=***');`. If it's not working, then prepend a back slash (the "\" character) to "PDO": `$conn = new \PDO('pgsql:host=***;dbname=***;user=***;password=***');`

Comment: could be a php.ini issue

Comment: Was everything restarted, including the server?

Comment: I did a restart before posting this but I did another one today. The error seemed to change between all that time. I tried both `=new PDO` and `=new /PDO`

The new error reads `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in `

Comment: I took a look at the php.ini I found the parts about PDO:
`
[Pdo]
; Whether to pool ODBC connections. Can be one of "strict", "relaxed" or "off"
; http://php.net/pdo-odbc.connection-pooling
;pdo_odbc.connection_pooling=strict

;pdo_odbc.db2_instance_name

[Pdo_mysql]
; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.cache_size
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.default-socket
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched out PDO and put in `pg_connect`. It seems to connect to the database just fine. I'll have to keep an eye on it to make sure it is working properly.